# How can I add up the numeric values given by a pl/sql loop into one single value?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure which outputs to a .csv file, it basically produces a heading for some values and then lists the values underneath. I am trying to adapt that code to just add all those values up. I will put them in another heading within the same csv file under "TOTAL" or similar.

I haven't tried anything with this yet because to be honest I am stumped with regards to how I can add up the values that result from the looped output.

My code is basically, this

```
create or replace procedure PROJECT is
  --variables
  l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
  ROW_COUNT number;
  file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
BEGIN
  utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,ROW_COUNT');

  --main loop
  for rws in (select /*+parallel */ owner, table_name
                from dba_tables@DB1 a
               where table_name in (select table_name
                                      from meta_table
                                     where driver_table is not null
                                       and additional_joins is null)
                 and a.owner in (select distinct schema
                                   from meta_table c)
               order by table_name)
 loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from '     ||rws.owner||'.'||rws.table_name || '@' || l_dblink into ROW_COUNT;
utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                  rws.OWNER || ',' ||
                  rws.TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
                  ROW_COUNT);
  end loop;
END PROJECT;
/
```

Which gives output like this:

```
OWNER       TABLE_NAME  ROW_COUNT
SCOUSE_BOB  KELLOGS     1000
SCOUSE_BOB  UNCLE_TOBY  4000
```

What I seek is a means by which to add these ROW_COUNTS up.

I will add a new utl_file.put_line with

```
TOTALS
```

But how do I get PL/SQL to sum up the values and produce '5000'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a variable to hold the Total. Add individual sums inside the loop. `utl_file.put_line` to display it will be outside the loop.

```
create or replace procedure PROJECT is
  --variables
  l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
  ROW_COUNT number;
  file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
  v_total number := 0;  
BEGIN
  utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,ROW_COUNT');

  --main loop
for rws in (select /*+parallel */ owner, table_name
               from dba_tables@DB1 a
             where table_name in (select table_name
                                    from meta_table
                                  where driver_table is not null
                                  and additional_joins is null)
               and a.owner in (select distinct schema
                                   from meta_table c)
               order by table_name)
 loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from '  
     ||rws.owner||'.'||rws.table_name 
     || '@'     || l_dblink into ROW_COUNT;

    v_total := v_total + ROW_COUNT; 
   utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                     rws.OWNER || ',' ||
                     rws.TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
                     ROW_COUNT);

  end loop;

     utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                     'Total '|| v_total
                     );

END PROJECT;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an assignment inside the last loop as

```
TOTALS := TOTALS + ROW_COUNT;
```

where `TOTALS` is a local variable, defined with `number` data type

and print after `end loop` as

```
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'Total count : '||TOTALS);
```